# What is the minimum permission needed for the client side people picker to work for a user

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, error, 2019, clientpeoplepicker

I have implemented client side people in SharePoint 2019 site in a custom form using plain HTML and jQuery. Requirement is to give user enough permission to use people picker but restrict from add/edit/delete data in Site Contents.

Problem statement: The user with Contribute permission is able to resolve user in people picker. Where as user with Limited Access permission get error in user resolution in people picker.

I tried creating custom permission to meet the requirement. But if I remove edit/delete/add list item permission then client side people picker does not work.
Gives following error:

> Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server.

Would appreciate any help, suggestions or pointer to resolve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test,  the "View Only" permission level would be enough to be able to resolve user in people picker.